# Use multiple name for an input type

Tags: php, html

This is the code line for user login in which user logs in through his user name. i want to edit it in such a way that it lets user login from both email id or user name. i think we will have to use two name but syntax won't be right then. tell a way to do so.

```
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
  $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-ZA-z0-9]#i', '',$_POST["user_login"]); //filter everything but numbers and letters
  $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-ZA-z0-9]#i', '',$_POST["password_login"]);//filter everything but number and letter
$password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5'LIMIT 1");//query whether user exists
//Check for their existence
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//Count the number of rows entered
if ($userCount ==1){
  while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
  }
   $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
  $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
  $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
  header("location: welcome.php");
  exit();
}else {
  echo 'Information is incorrect, try again';
  exit();
}
}
?>
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="60%" valign="top">

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user_login" size="25" placeholder="Username"><br>
  <input type="password" name="password_login" size="47" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
    </td>
```

Comment: The code you would need to change is not only in the HTML. You would need to modify the backend as well including the query that handles the login.

Comment: deal with this issue on the processing page, not the form page. perhaps you could do a check via strpos() if the data has a @ within it, and if so, check for proper email syntax and if that is valid, consider it an email and not username.

Comment: backend stuff is done only thing remains is in this line of code

Comment: well you cant have multiple names for a single input so your backend is going to need some refactoring if this is the point you ended at.

Comment: Without seeing the backend code, there is literally no way for anybody here to help.

Comment: updated @JeremyHarris

Comment: That `preg_replace` will ruin any email.

Comment: can you please provide code with changes then

Answer (score 2):

You really should be dealing with this type of checking on the backend/processing page.

A simple check, such as the below quasi example, is about as simple as it can get:  *(obviously requires additional security validations)*

```php
if(filter_var($_POST["user_login"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $sql_prepare = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1';
}
else {
    $sql_prepare = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1';
}
```

But yeah, this really is about as easy of a way as there is to resolve your case.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create different query based on user input at username.

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  // is email
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5'LIMIT 1");//query whether user exists
} else {
  // not email
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5'LIMIT 1");//query whether user exists
}
```

Comment: please provide the code with full changes
it was a bit confusing

Comment: Because it isn't otherwise specified, dropping variables into the middle of a sql query like this opens you up to sql injection problems in your future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change your SQL to something like this. It will compare both the email and username fields for a match.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE (username='$user_login' OR email='$user_login') AND password='$password_login_md5' LIMIT 1";
```

You should also consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the `mysql_*` functions, and consider hashing your passwords instead of using `md5()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little bit check using `filter_var` function for email validation. If the function returns `false`, it is definitely not going to be a valid email. Based on this, you can modify your query a little bit like the following code:

```
function is_email($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if(is_email($user_login)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email ='{$user_login}' AND password = '{$password_login_md5}' LIMIT 1");
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$user_login}' AND password = '{$password_login_md5}' LIMIT 1");
}
```

In order to avoid any confusion for you, I'm posting the whole code here just by changing few things in the existing code:

```
function is_email($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-ZA-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); //filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-ZA-z0-9]#i', '',$_POST["password_login"]); //filter everything but number and letter
    $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);

    if(is_email($user_login)) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email ='{$user_login}' AND password = '{$password_login_md5}' LIMIT 1");
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{$user_login}' AND password = '{$password_login_md5}' LIMIT 1");
    }

    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows entered

    if($userCount ==1) {
        while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $id = $row["id"];
        }
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
        $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
        header("location: welcome.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'Information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to bring few things into your attention about your code.

1. Remove regular expression for `$user_login` because you're only allowing numbers and alphabets. This would not accept email format. You can also pass regular expression like `#[^A-ZA-z0-9@_.]#i` to accept few other characters like `@`, `_`, `.` and like so if you're going to restrict the input to only allowed characters.
2. Avoid using deprecated `mysql`extension. Either use `mysqli` or `PDO`.
3. Use prepared statements in `mysqli` or `PDO` to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it says undefined variable username

Comment: It should be `$user_login` not `$username`. Modified the code now.

Comment: @Abela I've posted my answer with my own views. He needed the whole code to avoid confusions from other answers. I've posted the sample code and also attached it to his existing code and also did few explanations I could on my own.

Comment: @sanchit I've modified the code. You can check it out now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: even after entering the correct information it doesn't login and displays "Information is incorrect, try again"

Comment: @Perumal93  even after entering the correct information it doesn't login and displays "Information is incorrect, try again"

Comment: looks like changes need to be made in html too. @Perumal93

Comment: This happens when you enter email. Right?